# Trick to use file paths with spaces in Mallet (Terminal, OSx)?

Tags: macos, terminal, mallet

Is there  a trick to be able to use file paths with spaces in Mallet through the terminal on mac?

For example, all of the following give me errors:

escaping the space

```
./bin/mallet import-dir  --input /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/MY_NAME/Desktop/en --output /Users/MY_NAME/Desktop/en.mallet --remove-stopwords TRUE --keep-sequence TRUE
```

double quotes, no escapes

```
./bin/mallet import-dir --input "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/MY_NAME/Desktop/en" --output /Users/MY_NAME/Desktop/en.mallet --remove-stopwords TRUE --keep-sequence TRUE
```

and, with double quotes

```
./bin/mallet import-dir --input "/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/MY_NAME/Desktop/en" --output /Users/MY_NAME/Desktop/en.mallet --remove-stopwords TRUE --keep-sequence TRUE
```

and finally with single quotes

```
./bin/mallet import-dir --input '/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/MY_NAME/Desktop/en' --output /Users/MY_NAME/Desktop/en.mallet --remove-stopwords TRUE --keep-sequence TRUE
```

They all want to treat the folder as multiple folders, split on the space:

```
Labels = 
   /Volumes/Macintosh\
   HD/Users/MY_NAME/Desktop/en
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: /Volumes/Macintosh\ is not a directory.
    at cc.mallet.pipe.iterator.FileIterator.<init>(FileIterator.java:108)
    at cc.mallet.pipe.iterator.FileIterator.<init>(FileIterator.java:145)
    at cc.mallet.classify.tui.Text2Vectors.main(Text2Vectors.java:322)
```

Is there anyway around this, other than renaming all of my files with spaces to underscores? (I understand that I don't need to type /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/... but can just start at /Users. This was just an example.)

Comment: Try with double quote without backslashes

Comment: same error, I'll update question though with that info.

Comment: See this [github issue](https://github.com/mimno/Mallet/issues/63)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `import-dir` is designed to take multiple directories as input. The argument parser would need a way to distinguish this use case from the "escaped space" use case, keeping in mind that Windows paths can end in `\`.

The best way to support both cases might be to add a `--single-input` option that would take its argument as a single string.

I also find that the spreadsheet-style `import-file` command is almost always preferable to working with directories.

Answer (score 1):

As a work around you could:

(1) write some code to read the directory contents and generate a single examples file for use with:

bin/mallet input-file

Here's the mallet quick-start page for importing which describes the input-file version: http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/import.php

(2) Generate a symbolic link to the folder in a location without any spaces in it