# How to deal with spaces in cmd line in Mallet?

Tags: java, windows, cmd, windows-7-x64, mallet

If I run [Mallet](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/) in `cmd` for a path without spaces, it is ok.

Mallet import-dir --input E:\Mallet\mallet-2.0.8RC3\sample-data\web\en --output E:\Mallet\topicout\weben.mallet --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords

Above is ok. I copy those files under \en into another folder whose path contains spaces. I use quotation marks below, but it does not work. Cmd prompts error  **data\eco**. Can you help me how to deal with spaces in path for this command?

Mallet import-dir --input "F:\0economist data\eco data\final economist 1991-2016 8 country from Abi Proquest\All article\cn article\cn_1991" --output "F:\0economist data\eco data\final economist 1991-2016 8 country from Abi Proquest\All article\cn article\cn_1991_lda\cn91.mallet" --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords

How can I handle spaces in paths on the cmd line?

I am using Mallet 2.0.8, on Windows 7.

Comment: First, are you confident that the directory paths which contain a SPACE character are correct? Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38796435/trick-to-use-file-paths-with-spaces-in-mallet-terminal-osx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Please look for Mallet error messages.  If you find any, please update your post accordingly.
2. Perhaps the DOS command prompt doesn't like your path.  SUGGESTION:

   - Type `dir "F:\0economist data\eco data\final economist 1991-2016 8 country from Abi Proquest\All article\cn article\cn_1991"` and `dir "F:\0economist data\eco data\final economist 1991-2016 8 country from Abi Proquest\All article\cn article\cn_1991_lda\cn91.mallet"` to verify both paths
3. Perhaps Java (by way of Mallet) can't handle the spaces.  SUGGESTIONS:

   - Consider changing your path arguments to `F:/0economist data/eco data/final economist 1991-2016 8 country from Abi Proquest/All article/cn article/cn_1991"` and  "F:/0economist data/eco data/final economist 1991-2016 8 country from Abi Proquest/All article/cn article/cn_1991_lda/cn91.mallet"`
   - Consider using `dir/x` and use the 8.3 equivalent

Comment: thank you so much. I tested and did according to your third suggestion.